# Why is ag printing blank lines from this file?

Tags: regular-expression, search, ag

I want to use [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/master/doc/ag.1.md) to print the classes and their methods in a python file. I thought that this would be easy using:

```
ag --context=0 --nocolor -os '^\s*(def|class)\s+[_A-Za-z]*' prog.py
```

but for reasons I don't understand this is also matching blank lines. For example, if you make prog.py the following

```
class MyFavouriteClass
    def __init__

    def __contains__
        blah    
class MyNextFavouriteClass
    def _repr_

    def __iter__
```

then it returns the full file, including the blank lines, *except* for the line containing `blah`. Of course, I can always pipe the output into something else to remove the blank lines but I'd rather get it right the first time.

I suspect that the problem has nothing to do with the regular expression and, instead, that it's a feature of `ag`'s `--context`, `--after` and `--before` flags but I can't find a combination of these that does what I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: `--context=1` give you one line before and after matches.

Comment: @cuonglm I first tried `--context=0` and it still gives me the blank lines.  The `--context=1` slipped in after a few edits. You're right in that I should have kept `--context=0` in the question -- now fixed. Unfortunately,  this doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the `--context`, but the `\s*` at the start of your regex pattern.
It seems `ag` doesn't search line-by-line like normal `grep`, but looks at the whole file in one go (or at least several lines at a time). A bit like this Perl one-liner would:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print "$&\n" while /^\s*(def|class)\s+[_A-Za-z]*/msg' ../prog.py
```

So, since `\s` matches any whitespace, including newlines, it matches the previous empty line, the newline, spaces in front of the next, and then the `def` keyword. If you add an empty line before the `blah` line, it's not printed, since `blah` doesn't fit the pattern.

To get rid the unwanted match, use `/^ *...`  or `/^[ \t]*...` instead of `/^\s*...`. (space+asterisk in the first one)